# php memcached persistence between requests

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I am having a difficulty understanding why memcached connection doesn't persist between requests. I use this code to test if memcached remembers the added servers:

```
$mc = new Memcached('cache1');
var_dump($mc->getServerList());
$mc->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

the result I expected was that on each page load the `var_dump`ed `getServerList` array would grow with added servers but I keep getting 0 servers in the list.

Do I have a wrong assumption of how memcached persistence is supposed to work?
Or is there some PHP setting I need to change?

Obviously the following works but it's not persisted through different requests:

```
$mc = new Memcached('cache1');
var_dump($mc->getServerList());
$mc->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$mc2 = new Memcached('cache1');
$mc2->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
var_dump($mc->getServerList()); // as expected it shows 2 servers so it is persisted within the request but not across requests
```

`phpinfo` says fastCGI is enabled if it matters.

I read all these warnings regarding adding servers without checking if they already exist but right now it doesn't matter because they never exist...

Thank you.

Comment: The server persists, but when you create a new Memcached object this is more a client object.  When you add a server to this, you are effectively saying - use that server to service the requests.

Comment: Hi Nigel, Thanks for your response. I realize the server persists in the background and that new memcached object is a client that interfaces with the server, but I read on php.net that when you supply the memcached constructor an ID the client becomes persistent, now the question is persistent in what sense? can I get the client to persist between page refreshes?(then the comments about checking the servers list before adding servers makes sense) or is it just within a single request(not as useful I think)

Comment: if you have a PHP development environment set up can you please try running the code above and write here if you get a similar or different result? Thanks again!